# How to assign JSON field from one data source to another in Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I have two different JSON data coming into my Logic App:

Data 1:

```
[
   {
      "EmployeeCode":"123",
      "Username":"abc"
   },
   {
      "EmployeeCode":"456",
      "Username":"def"
   }
]
```

Data 2:

```
[
   {
      "EmployeeCode":"123",
      "Team":"IT"
   },
   {
      "EmployeeCode":"456",
      "Team":"Finance"
   }
]
```

And I want to generate final output like this:

Final output:

```
[
   {
      "EmployeeCode":"123",
      "Username":"abc",
      "Team":"IT"
   },
   {
      "EmployeeCode":"456",
      "Username":"def",
      "Team":"Finance"
   }
]
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this in Logic App itself? Without using JavaScript or Azure Function or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from our end here is how we could able to achieve your requirement.

First, we have used 2 Parse JSON for each data to extract the items in the JSON.

[image]

then used a condition connector to compare the EmployeeCode, and then merged using compose connector.

[image]

However to make the whole JSON to be used for future purposes we have initialized an array variable and then appended the successful runs from the condition connector. Here is my logic app.

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]

Below is the code view of my logic app

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "FinalJSON": {
                "inputs": "@variables('FinalJson')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "For_each_2": {
                        "actions": {
                            "Condition": {
                                "actions": {
                                    "Append_to_array_variable": {
                                        "inputs": {
                                            "name": "FinalJson",
                                            "value": "@outputs('Compose')"
                                        },
                                        "runAfter": {
                                            "Compose": [
                                                "Succeeded"
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                                    },
                                    "Compose": {
                                        "inputs": {
                                            "EmployeeCode": "@{items('For_each')['EmployeeCode']}",
                                            "Team": "@{items('For_each_2')['Team']}",
                                            "Username": "@{items('For_each')['Username']}"
                                        },
                                        "runAfter": {},
                                        "type": "Compose"
                                    }
                                },
                                "expression": {
                                    "and": [
                                        {
                                            "equals": [
                                                "@items('For_each')['EmployeeCode']",
                                                "@items('For_each_2')['EmployeeCode']"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "runAfter": {},
                                "type": "If"
                            }
                        },
                        "foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON2')",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Foreach"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON1')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "FinalJson",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "JSON1": {
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "EmployeeCode": "123",
                        "Username": "abc"
                    },
                    {
                        "EmployeeCode": "456",
                        "Username": "def"
                    }
                ],
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "JSON2": {
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "EmployeeCode": "123",
                        "Team": "IT"
                    },
                    {
                        "EmployeeCode": "456",
                        "Team": "Finance"
                    }
                ],
                "runAfter": {
                    "JSON1": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Parse_JSON1": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@outputs('JSON1')",
                    "schema": {
                        "items": {
                            "properties": {
                                "EmployeeCode": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Username": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "EmployeeCode",
                                "Username"
                            ],
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "type": "array"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "JSON2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Parse_JSON2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@outputs('JSON2')",
                    "schema": {
                        "items": {
                            "properties": {
                                "EmployeeCode": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "Team": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "required": [
                                "EmployeeCode",
                                "Team"
                            ],
                            "type": "object"
                        },
                        "type": "array"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON1": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: This is great and working like a charm on smaller datasets; however, any idea on how to increase the performace for larger datasets? For example, If I have 1000 records in JSON1 and 500 records in JSON2, the 'For_each, For_each_2, and Condition' will take a 2-3 hours with this logic. Any suggestion would be appreciated.